# Using an invalid C# keyword name when exporting to JSON

Tags: c#, json

I am using a third party api that expects JSON with keyword names like "key-name".

Using Entity Framework I do the following

```
var result = _context.data.Select(d => new 
{
    keyName = x.name
});
return Json(new {result = result});
```

Is there a way to use the appropriate value without replacing the strings after generation manually?

Comment: I wouldn't go with replacing strings in your already constructed JSON. You should put it in a dictionary with the appropriate property names, and serializing the dictionary. Much less error-prone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new class for json result.
e.g:

```
public class JsonResult{

[JsonProperty(Name="key-name")]
   public string KeyName{get;set;}
}

var result = _context.data.Select(d => new JsonResult
{
    KeyName = x.name
});
return Json(new {result = result});
```